# Multi-tenants == Multi-sites?

Tags: django, laravel, multi-tenant

Is tenancyforlaravel the equivalent to django's [django-multisite](https://pypi.org/project/django-multisite/) + ALLOWED_HOSTS ?

I created a bunch of related websites pointing the same Django app on my shared server.

I am looking for the Laravel equivalent for a new project using the similar methodologies.

Laravel only because there are many built-in solutions for SaaS. But I can't seem to relate the word multi-tenancy with multi-sites. Are both ditto ?

(WordPress has a similar (same?) thing called Multisite)